# Grails multi select plugin not working

Tags: grails, multi-select

I have 6 dropdowns in my grails application written using g select tags and now I need multiple selections in all the dropdowns but I am not able to implement this using the [Grails multi select plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/multi-select)

First of all I have included plugins - multiselect and resources in my Buildconfig.groovy using the following lines :

```
compile ":multi-select:0.2"
runtime ":resources:1.2.2"
```

The following codes are in my "index.gsp" file

My earlier code with basic single selection drop down :

```
<g:select from="['AFFILIATES', 'CSE','DISPLAYADS','EMAIL','MOBILEWEB','OTHERS','ORGANIC','SEO', 'SEM']" name="mv" id = "mv" 
           onchange="${remoteFunction(
           controller:'Com', 
           action:'ajaxGetMv', 
           // params:'\'mv=\' + escape(this.value)',
           params:'\'mv=\'+this.value+\'&department=\'+$(\'department\').value+\'&device=\'+$(\'device\').value+\'&browser=\'+$(\'browser\').value+\'&platform=\'+$(\'platform\').value+\'&time_period=\'+$(\'time_period\').value+\'&metric=\'+$(\'metric\').value',
           onSuccess: 'printpgtyp(data)')}"
></g:select>
```

This has to be changed to something like below : 
Attempt at multi select dropdown :

```
<ui:multiSelect from="['AFFILIATES', 'CSE','DISPLAYADS','EMAIL','MOBILEWEB','OTHERS','ORGANIC','SEO', 'SEM']" multiple="yes" name="mv" id = "mv" noSelection="['':'Select One']" 
           onchange="${remoteFunction(
           controller:'Com', 
           action:'ajaxGetMv', 
           // params:'\'mv=\' + escape(this.value)',
           params:'\'mv=\'+this.value+\'&department=\'+$(\'department\').value+\'&device=\'+$(\'device\').value+\'&browser=\'+$(\'browser\').value+\'&platform=\'+$(\'platform\').value+\'&time_period=\'+$(\'time_period\').value+\'&metric=\'+$(\'metric\').value',
           onSuccess: 'printpgtyp(data)')}"
/>
```

Also, I have added the following line in index.gsp outside the  tag (form tag contains all my g select tags - dropdowns)

```
<ui:resources includeJQuery="true"/>
```

It is not clear if this should be true/false as the results are same in both cases. [Reference link](https://github.com/IntelliGrape/Grails-Multi-Select-Plugin/wiki/Usage)

After all this, I am still getting the same dropdown as before and there is no multiple selections yet. I am using Grails - 2.3.4
What am I missing here? What else should I add/remove? Are the steps followed correct?

Any suggestions/feedback will be highly appreciated.

UPDATE :

Using this in index.gsp now:

```
<g:select from="['AFFILIATES', 'CSE','DISPLAYADS','EMAIL','MOBILEWEB','OTHERS','ORGANIC','SEO', 'SEM']" name="mv" id = "mv" multiple="true"
           onchange="${remoteFunction(
           controller:'Com', 
           action:'ajaxGetMv', 
           // params:'\'mv=\' + escape(this.value)',
           params:'\'mv=\'+this.value+\'&department=\'+$(\'department\').value+\'&device=\'+$(\'device\').value+\'&browser=\'+$(\'browser\').value+\'&platform=\'+$(\'platform\').value+\'&time_period=\'+$(\'time_period\').value+\'&metric=\'+$(\'metric\').value',
           onSuccess: 'printpgtyp(data)')}"
></g:select>
```

And controller is like this

```
    def ajaxGetMv = {
            if(params.metric == 'Marketing visits')
            {
            def com = Com.executeQuery("select p.date_hour, p.visits, case when visits_ly IN (0,null) THEN 0 ELSE ((visits/visits_ly - 1)*100) END as yoy, case when visits_lw IN (0,null) THEN 0 ELSE ((visits/visits_lw - 1)*100) END as wow, p.mv, p.browser, p.department, p.platform, p.device, p.time_period from Com p where p.department = ? and p.device = ? and p.browser = ? and p.platform = ? and p.mv = ? and p.time_period = ? order by col_0_0_ asc ",[params.department, params.device, params.browser, params.platform, params.mv, params.time_period])
            render com as JSON
            }
//.........else if and so on for all my metrics
```

So now, index and controller communicate for only one value, how do I make them communicate for multiple selections here?
I think controller will have to change here

Answer (score 1):

Grails 2.x supports multi select without a plugin.  Below is a example from the documentation.  The UI for multi select is not the best.

```
// create multiple select
<g:select name="cars"
      from="${Car.list()}"
      value="${person?.cars*.id}"
      optionKey="id"
      multiple="true" />
```

Here is an example on how I accessed multi select checkboxes in the view and controller:

```
   <g:each in="${Car.findAllByActive(true)}" var="car">
        <div class="span4 checkbox">
             <g:checkBox name="cars" value="${car.id}" checked="${car in instance?.cars}" />
              <label>${car.name}</label>
        </div>
    </g:each>

    params.cars.each { it ->
        instance.cars.add(Car.findById(it as Long))
    }
```

Comment: I tried this, I am getting a different type of dropdown, where I am able to select multiple by pressing on control( which is weird) How should the multi select dropdown come exactly?
Also, It's still taking only the first selected value. Check my updated answer pls

Comment: The default html multi select is not the best UI.  I have used checkboxes instead and processed them with the controller code above since updates did not work as I would have expected.

Comment: the multi view is cos of multiple="true", what do you mean by first value ? do you mean the other paramters such as department etc are not showing up?